# Displaying two separate array values side by side

Tags: javascript

I've looked all over for an answer to my question but could not find a solution. I want to display values from two separate arrays side by side "**`without joining the arrays together`**."

Ex.

```
var names = ["Ben", "Joel", "Randy"];
var scores = [88, 99, 100];
```

I want them to display in a text box side by side without having to join or concatenate them. They need to remain separate for different operations.

Ex.

```
Ben, 88
Joel, 99
Randy, 100
```

Any help will be most appreciated! Thanks.

This is what I've tried:

```
var list = "";
for (var n in names) {
    for (var s in scores) {
        list = names[n] + ", " + scores[s]; 

    }

}
```

Comment: Run a loop and access both arrays with the count of the loop.

Comment: Would you know how to print out the values from a single array?  If so, the logic should be very similar for two arrays.

Comment: This is what I've tried:

Comment: Please do **NOT** post code in comments.  You can simply edit your original question to include your code.

Comment: @user1890525 -- While this may be all you know, there doesn't seem to be much effort shown in what you have tried for a solution. Even if what you've tried is completely wrong and doesn't work, still show it, it lets us know you're making an effort to solve your problem.

Comment: Try using _only one_ **traditional** for loop: `for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)`.  Then you can use `i` to access elements from both arrays.  There is no reason for two loops here.  Try thinking about what your code does rather than just writing down familiar constructs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var names = ["Ben", "Joel", "Randy"];
var scores = [88, 99, 100];

var text=names.map(function(itm,i){
   return [itm,scores[i]];
}).join('<br>');
```

//return text to some element's innerHTML

// or delimit with '\n' for text box or textarea value

Comment: I always forget about the `.map()` function until someone posts it.

Comment: This helped! instead of .join('<br>') I used .join("\n") to achieve the correct results. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty much a basic for-loop you are looking for (assuming both arrays will always be the same size):

```
for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    var nameString = names[i] + "   " + scores[i];
    //do stuff with nameString
}
```

Answer (score 1):

OP said (and I quote)

> This is what I've tried:
>
> ```
> var list = "";
> for (var n in names) {
>   for (var s in scores) {
>     list = names[n] + ", " + scores[s]; 
>   }
> }
> ```

You problem here is that you are nesting loops. This gives you the *cartesian product* of the two sets (e.g. if your `names` is of length 10 and your 'scores' is of length 20, you'll get 200 rows as a result, one for each name/score combination.

An approach like this is your best bet as it deals with lists of differing lengths:

```
var names = [ ... ] ;
var scores =  [ ... ] ;
var cnt = names.length < scores.length ? names.length : scores.length ;
var i = j = 0 ;

// process all matching elements
while ( i < cnt && j < cnt )
{
  process( name[i++] , score[i++] ) ;
}

// process names w/o scores
while ( i < cnt )
{
  process( names[i++] , null ) ;
}

// process scores w/o names
while ( j < cnt )
{
  process( null , scores[j++] ) ;
}
```

You could, of course do it more concisely, all in one loop, but this approach makes your intent clear to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

```
var i;

for(i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
{
   document.write(names[i] + " " + scores[i] + "<br>"); 
}
```

Or is that not what you are looking for? I am not sure if I "joined" them.